# WindowsPhone 8 IE10 input field event isn´t called

Tags: javascript, mobile, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I am building a mobile web app.
There is one page where i have several inputfields of the type:

```
<input id="heightinput" type="textfield" pattern="\d*"/>
```

The app is listening to these inputfields with:

```
var whv = that.weightheightValidate.bind(that);
$("#heightinput").on("input",whv);
$("#heightinput").on("blur",whv);
$("#heightinput").on("deactivate",whv);
$("#heightinput").on("change",whv);
```

Everything works very fine on IOS and Android. BUT NOT on Windows8 Phone with IE10 Browser.
Where it fails is the blur event ( or deactivate or focusout) if i made my input and press the return button.
The return button closes the keyboard overlay, but doesnt trigger any events I know.
Does anyone know the right event for this ? Or a workaround?
EDIT: if i tap somewhere on the screen, the blur event is fired, but i has to fire if i press return.

Comment: there is no input type='textfield'

Comment: You are right, but this still isnt the solution.

Comment: I think you need to apply tab indexes to the input fields.

Comment: I'm not familar with Windows-phone-8, though do you think you meant 'this' instead of 'that'?

Comment: @Ian Brindley:tab indexes made no difference.

Comment: @reporter : In this case var that == this.

Comment: Can you provide more source code? What will happen if you write '$(that).weightheightValidate.bind(that);'

Comment: @reporter: that or this is a quite complex object. Its not a dom object, so $(that) would make no sense in this case.
The binding is fine it wors for the input event. I am just in need for an IE10 Event something like onIfThe ReturnButtonInTheOverlayKeyboardHasBeenPressed ... instead of blur, which isnt fired.

Comment: If you are using IE from within an App, then when using the back button to hide the virtual keyboard, the blur event is not fired (still a problem in 8.1). This answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981817/windows-phone-8-missing-blur-event-in-ie10-when-back-button-pressed says to use the IE deactivate event type instead. Here is a test page http://output.jsbin.com/decuko/4/quiet  or this  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/blurfocus.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding `deactivate` it to the document like this,

```
$(document).on('blur deactivate', '#heightinput', whv);
```

Worked for me. Good Luck!!